# how to transfer a files one system to another system

Tags: c#

how to transfer a files from a folder of one system to another system in particular folder in c#.net 
can any help me on this topic

Comment: Can you clarify? You just wanna copy files from one folder to another one?

Comment: Create a network share, set up permissions correctly, ensure you are connected (`NET USE` via the command prompt, which you can access indirectly in C#), and use regular file copy operations.

Comment: It's completely up to the machines, their OS and network relation. More info is needed.

Comment: @Federico, he did say "from a folder of one system to another system"

Answer (score 3):

If you have a UNC with the proper permissions you can just do this:

```
File.Copy(SourceFile, UncDestinationFile);
```

You can find out more by [reading the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx).

If you are not familiar with UNC paths I suggest you [read up on it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Usually a UNC looks like:

```
\\Machine\DestinationFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.Move(source, destination)
```

Should do it provided you have the required permissions and of course both machines are on the same network

Here is the MSDN documentation and an example as well
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

As an example. Here is some code that will move all files from source to destination:
Be sure to replace "\machinename\folder" with your actual names and similarly the destination folder.

```
  var sourceFolder = "\\machiename\folder";
  var destFolder = @"C:\temp\";
  foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(sourceFolder))
    File.Move(file, destFolder + Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Since it's not clear you in your question. File.Move() will "move" the files. That is the files will no longer exist in "destination. File.Copy() will copy files and so you'll have the files in both source and destination after you finish.

Comment: Using de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.210.1.1")
            Using adSearch As New DirectorySearcher(de)
                adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=boddus)"
                Dim adSearchResult As SearchResult = adSearch.FindOne()
            End Using
        End Using                                                                   @shiva i have done upto this part i have got the result of that particular user and how do i assign a folder and i hv to place file all files in another system

Comment: @praveen are you intentionally using DirectoryServices? That's wasn't clear at all in your question. I'll work on som sample code and edit my answer and post a comment here.

Comment: @praveen what is result? What type is it. And does it have a Path property?

Comment: path was correct only ....i need to knw how connect with that computer and i have to pass file to particular folder

Comment: @praveen, I'm not in a domain so I can't attempt to do what you're doing. However, can you tell me why you're using DirectoryServices? You should know that your question and title are completely misleading. If **have** to use DirectoryServices then I suggest posting another question and clearly specifying that you're using (and have to use) DirectoryServices. If you're interested in moving files from one system to another, my answer has the solution to that.